# 2d-array with "wrapped edges" in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, subclass

Warning: I'm a C# newb. Besides answering my questions, if you have any tips in general after seeing my code, they are welcome.

Let's say I define a two-dimensional array of size 10x10 in C#:

```
var arr = new int[10,10];
```

It is an error to access elements with indices out of the range 0-9. In some applications, (e.g. some games where the 2d-array represents a world) it's necessary to "wrap" the edges of the array. So for example

```
arr[-1, 0]
```

would actually refer to the element at arr[9,0].

One approach I've been using is the following class. I didn't subclass System.Array because C# apparently forbids doing so.

Example usage:

```
var grid = new Grid(10,10);
grid.set(-1, 0, 100); // Set element at (-1,0) to value 100.
grid.at(-1,0); // retrieve element at (-1,0)
```

The class itself:

```
class Grid
{
    public int[,] state;

    public int width { get { return state.GetLength(0); } }
    public int height { get { return state.GetLength(1); } }

    public Grid(int width_init, int height_init)
    {
        state = new int[width_init, height_init];
    }

    int mod(int a, int b)
    {
        if (a >= 0)
            return a % b;
        else
            return (b + a % b) % b;
    }

    int wrap_x(int x) { return mod(x, width); }
    int wrap_y(int y) { return mod(y, height); }

    public int at(int x, int y)
    {
        return state[wrap_x(x), wrap_y(y)];
    }

    public void set(int x, int y, int val)
    {
        state[wrap_x(x), wrap_y(y)] = val;
    }    

    // more stuff here...
}
```

**Question:** Is there a game/creative-coding framework out there that provides this sort of class?

**Question:** Can you think of a simpler `mod` I can use in the above?

In order to process each element along with the corresponding "x" and "y", I use the following method:

```
public void each(Action<int, int, int> proc)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            proc(x, y, state[x, y]);
}
```

**Question:** I looked around for a similar method defined on System.Array but I didn't find one. Did I miss it?

**Question:** In the above, `for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)` is the common idiom expressing "go from zero up to N by 1". Is there a mechanism which expresses this in C#? I.e. I'd like to write the above as:

```
width.up_to((x) =>
    height.up_to((y) =>
        proc(x, y, state[x, y]);
```

where `up_to` would be a method on integers. Is there something like `up_to` already defined?

Similar to `map` from Scheme, here's a `map` method which applies a `Func` to each element and its corresponding indices. It returns a new `Grid`.

```
public Grid map(Func<int, int, int, int> proc)
{
    var grid = new Grid(width, height);
    each((x, y, val) => grid.state[x, y] = proc(x, y, val));
    return grid;
}
```

**Question:** Let's suppose I setup a subclass `class World : Grid` which adds additional instance variables. The trouble with the above `map` is that when called on an instance of `World`, you get a `Grid`, not a `World`. How should I fix this? Is this the wrong approach altogether? Perhaps a better design is to not subclass `Grid` but to have keep it as an instance variable in `World`.

Sorry for the long submission. :-)

**Update:** I asked the question about `upto` separately and got some [good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163946/is-there-an-upto-method-in-c).

Comment: You'll have better luck if you make each question a separate... question.

Comment: Ideally, you should ask questions one by one.

Comment: The more I think about your questions, the more I think some of them would well be received on codereview.stackexchange.com. Just post them one at a time :)

Comment: You should make it obvious that your class does wrapping.  A name like `WrappingGrid` might work.  `///` comments on methods might also work.

Comment: Let me recommend using a 1D array for internal storage. The two indices `i`, `j` can be combined to give `data[10*i+j]` for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One thing you can do to facilitate reference to your grid is overload `[,]`:

```
public int this[int x, int y]
{
    get { return state[wrap_x(x), wrap_y(y)]; }
    set { state[wrap_x(x), wrap_y(y)] = value; }
}
```

If you find the syntax more suitable, go for it.

Regarding your `mod` function, the best suggestion I can make is to make those variables (a and b) meaningful. `index` and `maxSize` oughta do it.

---

Other stuff:

- Your `state` variable should be private.
- Unless you absolutely, exclusively need ints, consider using a generic for the type of your `state` array. Your `Grid` class becomes `Grid<T>`.
- With the bracket `[,]` overload, you can get rid of your `at` and `set` functions.
- As for your World class, with a simplified Grid, the question to ask is this classic: is or has? IS your World a Grid or does it HAVE a Grid? Only you can answer that, but I'm leaning towards HAS.
- Consider a Grid constructor which takes a ready-made 2d array as a parameter:

Example:

```
public Grid(int[,] state)
{
    this.state = state;
}
```

- `mod` can be made valid for any value (multiple wrap around) with a slight modification.

Example:

```
int mod(int index, int maxSize)
{
    while (index < 0) index += maxSize;
    return index % maxSize;
}
```

Results:

- `mod(0,10)` => 0
- `mod(1,10)` => 1
- `mod(-1,10)` => 9
- `mod(10,10)` => 0
- `mod(-10,10)` => 0
- `mod(11,10)` => 1
- `mod(-11,10)` => 9

Comment: I'd considered doing that (overloading [,]) and now that you've encouraged it, I will probably do so. :-)

Comment: I made a mistake with the overload, please see the correction. It's actually an overload property :)

Comment: Not sure I understand your 3rd bullet point. The `set` method is used to set a particular location in the grid; how would a constructor help that?

Comment: I added a bullet about your World class, as well as a new mod function.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer MPelletier! Accepted!

Answer (score -1):

Just access the array with the modulo `%` function. For an `N` by `M` array use the following.

```
int x = A[i % N, j % M];
```

it will do exactly what you need. In your example use `arr[-1 % 10, 0 % 10]` instead of `arr[-1,0]`. There is no need for a wrapper function, or additional code!

Comment: In C# `-1 % 10` evaluates to -1, not 9. So the above wouldn't exactly work. :-)

Comment: Some languages do produce the "positive mod" with %, but not C#. The other issue (besides negatives) is that new code that refers to the same array will need to carry this strategy, so it has to be added every time. It's a lot of upkeep.

Comment: I knew I should have checked it before I posted. Maybe instead of `%` the wrapping function can be `i - (int)(N * Math.Floor((double)i / N))` which wraps the integer `i` from `0` to `N-1`.