# Is there an "upto" method in C#?

Tags: c#

Here's a bit of code which prints out the squares of the numbers from 0 to 9:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    Console.WriteLine(i*i);
```

Doing something from 0 to N by 1 via a `for` loop is a very common idiom.

Here's an `UpTo` method which expresses this:

```
class MathUtil
{
    public static void UpTo(int n, Action<int> proc)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            proc(i);
    }
}
```

The squares example above is now:

```
MathUtil.UpTo(10, (i) => Console.WriteLine(i * i));
```

My question is, does the standard C# library come with something like the above `UpTo`?

Ideally, I'd like a way to have 'UpTo' be a method on all integer objects. So I could do:

```
var n = 10;

n.UpTo(...);
```

Is this possible in C#?

Comment: It might be a matter of taste, but I consider the `for` variant to be a bit more readable than `UpTo`. In addition, it's extremely easy to modify the start number (`0`) or the incrementation method (`i++`) in the `for` variant. I think [Eric Lippert's comments on a `ForEach` method](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx) apply here as well.

Comment: @Heinzi Thanks for the link to Eric's article!

Comment: .NET Extensions Methods(http://dnpextensions.codeplex.com/) have an extension method for this. `5.times(...);`

Comment: This just made me think of the excellent article on the new 'goes to' (-->)and 'is approached by' (<--) operators, that were introduced in C# 4.0 - see Eric Lippert's blog for more details: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/04/01/somelastminutefeatures.aspx

Comment: @yas4891: Funny stuff :)

Comment: The thing is quite easy if you utilize snippets in VS. Just a matter of typing `for` and then two tab presses.. And `Times` is a better name for an extension method of this kind. Compare `10.Times(DoStuff)` to `10.Upto(DoStuff)`. Ruby has `times` keyword for similar thing.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Turn it into an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) (note the **this** before the `n` parameter, which defines the type this method operates on):

```
static class MathUtil
{
    public static void UpTo(this int n, Action<int> proc)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            proc(i);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
10.UpTo((i) => Console.WriteLine(i * i));
```

---

**Note:** The above method call isn't particularly intuitive though. Remember code is written once and read many times.

Maybe allowing something like below might be slightly better, but to be honest i'd still just write a `foreach` loop.

```
0.UpTo(10 /*or 9 maybe*/, (i) => Console.WriteLine(i * i));
```

If you wanted this, then you could write an extension method like this:

```
public static void UpTo(this int start, int end, Action<int> proc)
{
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
        proc(i);
}
```

Change `<` to `<=` if you want an inclusive upper bound.

Comment: I know this is what the OP asked for, but the syntax stinks: `10.UpTo(i => Console.WriteLine(i * i));` ... That would make no sense to me except for the fact that I know extension methods and the dirty tricks they afford :)

Comment: We have a winner! Thanks George!

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett: The amended answer addresses all my concerns.  gg!

Comment: I much prefer the `0.UpTo(10, /*blah*/)` version, it's more intuitive and more readable.

Comment: Ruby has a `times` method which works on integers. So that's another option for a name. Common Lisp has a `dotimes` macro.

Answer (score 24):

Take a look at LINQ [TakeWhile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.takewhile.aspx) or for your specific case of integers, use [Enumerable.Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx)

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(i => ...);
```

Arguably you shouldn't be putting an Action on the end there, see [comments on ForEach here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx).

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
public static class IntExtensions
{
    public static void UpTo(this int n, Action<int> proc)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            proc(i);
    }
}
```

With this you could write

```
10.UpTo(i => Console.WriteLine(i * i));
```

The function I wrote is called an **extension method**.
At design time you notice is not a native function because it has a different icon.
Estension methods are static methods or functions included in a static class and type they work on is the first param on which you must use `this` keyword.
In `IntExtensions` class you could write all methods you please; grouping them inside the same static class makes you easy manage them.

Answer (score 8):

wanna do it in one line ? here it goes:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 9).Select(i => i * i).ToList().ForEach(j=>Console.WriteLine("%d",j));
```

Comment: The 'ToList()' is required to call 'ForEach' as it's only exposed on lists and arrays.

Answer (score 6):

Try `Enumerable.Range`, possibly in combination with `Take` or `TakeWhile`:

```
IEnumerable<int> values = Enumerable.Range(0, 20)
    .Take(10); // Not necessary in this example

foreach(var value in values)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}

// or ...

foreach(var i in Enumerable.Range(0, 10))
{
    Console.WriteLine(i * i);
}
```

There is a `ForEach` on `List<T>` that you could use to get closer syntax to what you want, but I consider it bad form.  It takes a pure query/filter/transform syntax, that works in an effectively immutable fashion, and introduces side-effects.

For your future amusement you might want to check out [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx), [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx), and [`yield return`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx).  A lot of generator-type functionality and interesting syntax becomes possible when you use those three things in combination.  Although I would argue that this particular example isn't the best place to use them because the resulting syntax becomes a mess.

Answer (score 2):

Make your method like this in a static class "Extensions" for example:

```
public static void UpTo(this int n, Action<int> proc)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
        proc(i);
}
```

And the usage:

```
var n = 10;
n.UpTo(i => Console.WriteLine(i * i));
```

Hope this helps! :)